# Crear listview en un Fragment en android

Tags: android

Estoy creando una aplicación en la cual incluyo un `listview`, en un `Fragment`. Dicho `listview` ya lo había ejecutado en un activity normal y todo muy bien, ahora que lo quiero ejecutar en un `fragment`me salen varios errores.

**Este es mi codigo Java del fragment**

```
public class Fragmento01 extends Fragment {

ListView listView;
String[] elementos = {"jose", "pedro", "maria", "miguel", "luis", "daniel", "elena", "Laura", "Sofia"};
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,elementos);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmento01, container, false);
}
```

}

**este es mi codigo xml del fragmento**

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.jorge.appciudadanoconsciente.FragmentoInicio"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Cual es el error que recibes cuando ejecutas la aplicacion?

Comment: Ya hicisites la pregunta aquí: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31443/create-listview-in-fragment-android-crear-listview-en-un-fragmento-en-android. Por favor elimina una de las 2 preguntas. No hay necesidad de tener la misma pregunta 2 veces a partir de 2 cuentas diferentes.

Comment: Como la puedo borrar?, lo que pasa que la pregunta pasada estuvo mal planteada,  y la hice antes de tener cuenta en stackoverflow, ahora ya tengo cuenta y ya puedo comentar. 


Estos son los 3 errores que recibo:

cannot resolve method  'findViewId(?)'
       cannot resolve symbol 'listview'
        cannot resolve method  'getApplicationContext()'

Comment: Eres el mismo? http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31443/create-listview-in-fragment-android-crear-listview-en-un-fragmento-en-android Si tuvieras una cuenta tal vez tendrias ya suficiente reputacion. Tu titulo no tiene mucho que ver con la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que estas cometiendo es que estas buscando la Id de tu `listview` como si fuese parte de `onCreate` de una `Activity`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                         ViewGroup container, 
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmento01, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state) {
    super.onActivityCreated(state);
    listView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,elementos);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
}
```

Aqui buscamos la Id de tu `listview` desde `getView` y no buscando la Id en un layout. El view lo retornamos y configuramos en `onCreateView`

Comment: hice todo tal cual como me mencionaste y despues de intentar unos minutos, me sigue apareciendo el mismo error del listviewy el de getApplicationContext ---  cannot resolve symbol 'listview'  --- cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext()'

Comment: asi mismo sale otro error en esta linea: ---- ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,elementos); ---- el error lo propone en esta parte del codigo --- this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,elementos---

Comment: @JorgeAlbertoAnguianoTorres actualice mi respuesta! En el Toast reemplace GetContext por getActivity().getApplicationContext()

Comment: Vaya que grande! los errores desaparecen, ahora solo queda el del listview en esta linea --- listView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listview); --- el mensaje al pasar el cursor es cannot resolve symbol 'listview'

Comment: Actualice! Guarda gerView en una variable, creo que eso podria solucionar el problema

Comment: QUEDO EXCELENTE! MUCHAS GRACIAS!, al final no fue necesario el ultimo paso, seguía el error por error de android studio, ya que no había actualizado dicho error, actualice el Gradle y se actualizo todo el compilador, y fuera error. Grande gracias.

Comment: Ok! Voy a dejar como estaba me alegro que funcionara!

Comment: esta bien lo que comenta sioesi, cabe aclarar que estas declarando la listview en el oncreateview, y en los fragments en el oncreateview solo inflas la layout, no llamas a nada, tenes que hacer todas las declaraciones en el oncreateactivity :)  , la proxima vez nos ayudaria mucho que publicaras un logcat con los errores que te saltan

saludos

Answer (score 1):

Cambia esto:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

Por:

```
listView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Comment: Hice lo que me mencionaste y se me borro un error ahora solo tengo dos errores 

        cannot resolve symbol 'listview'
        cannot resolve method  'getApplicationContext()'

El error que se quito fue el de
        cannot resolve method  'findViewId(?)'

Answer (score 0):

tal cual dice sioesi, estas buscando el id de la vista en un layout que no lo contiene

Yo suelo trabajar asi y funciona perfecto:

```
public class test extends Fragment {
private View v;
private EditText editText;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    editText = v.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    return v;
}
```

}
de esa manera "guardas" la referencia a la vista en la variable v para poder usarla para inicializar los componentes dentro de la vista correcta

```
v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
```

luego, obtener la referencia que necesitas desde la variable "v". De esa forma podes inicializar todos los controles que estan dentro del xml asociado a ese fragmento y podras usarlos como acostumbras

`editText = v.findViewById(R.id.editText2);`

al final no olvides retornar la vista que esta guardada en la variable "v"

```
return v;
```